# How to retrieve FLS settings for a custom field

Tags: apex, metadata-api, profile, fls

I have a custom field `custom_field__c` in `Opportunity` object and using APEX or metadata API (workbench) is there a way to find what are the set field level security profile is set for that given custom field?

for an example, I need to know what profile is checked Visible/Read-Only.

below image is for ref.

[image]

Comment: Hope this helps:  https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profile.htm Checkout the ProfileFieldLevelSecurity part.

Answer (score 4):

You can query field permissions by using SOQL on the [`FieldPermissions`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm) object.

For example:

```
SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit FROM FieldPermissions
```

This would return a lot of rows: every field returned multiplied by the number of permission sets. So if you have 200 fields and 20 permission sets, you'll return 4000 rows. You can help reduce this by filtering based on object and specific profile. For example:

```
SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity'
AND ParentId IN (
  SELECT Id 
  FROM PermissionSet 
  WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
)
```

Or you could look at a specific field instead:

```
SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity'
AND Field = 'Opportunity.Custom_Field__c'
```

**Edit**

As Adrian said in the comments, the multiplier is against Permission Sets, not Profiles so I've updated the answer to reflect that fact. Furthermore:

> **PermissionsRead**
>
> If true, users assigned to the parent PermissionSet can view this field. A FieldPermissions record must have at minimum PermissionsRead set to true, or it will be deleted.

This is your "visible" column. In other words, should the User be able to see the field?

> **PermissionsEdit**
>
> If true, users assigned to the parent PermissionSet can edit this field. Requires PermissionsRead for the same field to be true.

This is your "read-only" column. Should the User be able to edit the field? Or, can they only read it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and what is `Read-Only` & `Visible` represent? in the FieldPermissions object?

Comment: I have updated my question so the new image shows exactly what I'm looking to achieve, I just need to know What System Administrator and Standard User have access to `Visible` & `Read-Only`

Comment: Multiplied by the number of permission sets, not profiles.

Comment: Adrian what do you mean by Multiplied by the number of permission sets? can you elaborate little bit more

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks for that! I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @NickKahn See my edit.

Comment: I thought so too but I have unchecked PermissionsEdit/PermissionsRead and query `SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE SObjectType = 'Opportunity'
AND ParentId IN (
  SELECT Id 
  FROM PermissionSet 
  WHERE PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator'
)` it still showing true to both Visible/Readonly isn't that suppose to show false if I unchecked?

Comment: @NickKahn Try with a different profile, ideally a custom one. System Administrator profiles tend to have access to everything whether you like it or not.

Comment: good point Dan that might be the case why I'm looking all true and I'm System Administrator so no wonder, I'm trying with another profile a custom one and will update you here shortly.

Comment: I created a standard user and select standard user profile and when I ran the query I get both(visible/readonly) returns me `true`.